# Nagios - Critical hard state if value increased

Tags: nagios

how can I set up a service check in a way, that its state goes to CRITICAL hard, whenever the value of a performance data increased?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for all the tips guys! :) It seems to me, that Nagios is not that trendy and popular nowdays. :)

Comment: lol :) You may wish to clarify your question a bit and provide a concrete example. Many nagios check plugins have different behavior with regard to performance data/check results, so it may be difficult to provide a general purpose answer.

Comment: Lets take the check_load as an example. Lets say, I want to get an alert, whenever the value of load5 increased. It should not depend on the check plugin itself, only on the configurations. I was hoping for a special service directive like "alert_on_perf_value_increase 0", or similar. Or maybe the issue could be solved with a macro. I don't know...